# Como inserir uma propriedade 'multiple' dentro de um Elemento HTML capturado pelo ID via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Gostaria de inserir a propriedade *'multiple'* via javascript, para meu código aceitar múltiplos arquivos:

```
file = document.getElementById('onetidIOFile');

<input type=​"file" name=​"fileupload0" id=​"onetidIOFile" class=​"ms-fileinput" size=​"56" title=​ 
"Nome">​
```

Neste código acima, ele só aceita somente um arquivo. Quero saber se é possível inserir a propriedade 'multiple', desta maneira: `type='file' multiple`

Answer (score -2):

Achei uma maneira de inserir, via javascript, o atributo multiple usando o `setAtribute`:

```
file.setAttribute('multiple','multiple');
```

Desta maneira atendeu o que eu desejava:
[image: saída do código acima]